# JTextField and JLabel not appearing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, jtextfield

My JLabel and JTextField are not appearing overtop the image and I'm not sure why. I've put the image on a JLabel and setOpaque(false) but no luck. Any advice? Thanks for the help in advance.

```
       private JTextField tf;
       private JLabel jl2;
       private JLabel jl3;

       public void window() {
           ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("hangman.png");
          JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();
          JPanel jp = new JPanel();
          jp.setOpaque(false); //!!
          jp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
          JLabel img = new JLabel(ic, JLabel.CENTER);
          img.setOpaque(false);
          JLabel jl = new JLabel("Enter a Letter:");
          jl.setFont(new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 20));
          tf = new JTextField(1);
          jl2 = new JLabel("Letters Used:    ");
          jl3 = new JLabel();//blank spaces
          tf.setFont(new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 20));
          jl2.setFont(new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 20));
          jp.add(jl);
          jp.add(tf);
          jp.add(jl2);
          jp.add(jl3);
          gameFrame.add(img);
          img.add(jp);
          gameFrame.setTitle("Hangman");
          gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          gameFrame.setIconImage(
          new ImageIcon("Hangman-Game-grey.png").getImage());
          gameFrame.setResizable(false);
          gameFrame.pack();
          gameFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          gameFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JLabel doesn't use a layout manager by default so components added to the label will not be painted.

Try setting the layout manager. Maybe:

```
img.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
```

or choose a layout that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You should add image, label and textfield objecs to panel, respectively. Then, you should add that panel to your frame. Also, put `gameFrame.add(img);` code before calling `jp.add()` methods. I don't know, if this is what you want but from what you try to do, I can say below code should work:

```
public void window()
        {
        ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("hangman.png");
        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setOpaque(false); // !!
        jp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
        JLabel img = new JLabel(ic, JLabel.CENTER);
        img.setOpaque(false);
        JLabel jl = new JLabel("Enter a Letter:");
        jl.setFont(new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        tf = new JTextField(1);
        jl2 = new JLabel("Letters Used:    ");
        jl3 = new JLabel();// blank spaces
        tf.setFont(new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        jl2.setFont(new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        jp.add(img);
        jp.add(jl);
        jp.add(tf);
        jp.add(jl2);
        jp.add(jl3);
        gameFrame.add(jp);
        gameFrame.setTitle("Hangman");
        gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gameFrame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("1.jpg").getImage());
        gameFrame.setResizable(false);
        gameFrame.pack();
        gameFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
```